# WebRTC' does not contain bitcode You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, webrtc, connectycube

My app works on the simulator when I run: `npx react-native run-ios`

However when I try to get the ipa file by 'Archive'-ing it via the .xcworkspace
I get the following error regarding WebRTC and bitcode.

How to fix this issue?

> ld:
> '/Users/bliss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DanceConnectyCube-czcpkmpwkpsbethjfvbfindeabwg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DanceConnectyCube/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/react-native-webrtc/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC'
> does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
> (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
> vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
> '/Users/bliss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DanceConnectyCube-czcpkmpwkpsbethjfvbfindeabwg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DanceConnectyCube/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/react-native-webrtc/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC'
> for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 3):

you need to remove bitcode in your ios project setting in xcode `target->build settings-> enable bitcode` or use a custom webrtc build that enable it at compile time (huge build).
I made one [here](https://github.com/pnoyelle/iOSWebRTCFramework)

edit:
a [build](https://github.com/pnoyelle/WebRTC_IOS) with bitcode and swiftmodule support
This Repo also have sh script that explain the procedure.

Comment: Is the one you made bitcode enabled?

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy i have both released with and without  bitcode. 
I made an other repository with the procedure explained in SH script and swiftmodule build, link in edit section. The best is that you compile your own if you need it for commecial app.

Answer (score 3):

For those came here with the same error:

If you are trying **to debug your app in your iPhone** you have to select bitcode=no in order to work.

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion

Comment: This is what solved it for me! Don't understand why it's downvoted to negative.